# AutoFac cannot resolve Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession in my integration test with mediatr

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, autofac, xunit

I want to write an integration test for a request send via mediator. Therefore I somehow need to resolve all necessary dependencies. Here is what I do:

```
public class GetCheckoutRequestTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void GetCheckoutRequest ()
    {
        //Arrange
        IMediator mediator = BuildMediator();
        GetCheckoutRequest request = new()
            {
                Id= "1090"
            };
        //Act
        SomeDto dto = mediator.Send(request);

        //Assert

    }

    IMediator BuildMediator() {
        //AutoFac
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly).AsImplementedInterfaces();

        var mediatrOpenTypes = new[] {
                typeof(IRequestHandler<,>)
            };

        foreach (var mediatrOpenType in mediatrOpenTypes) {
            builder
                .RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(GetCheckoutRequest.Handler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
                .AsClosedTypesOf(mediatrOpenType)
                .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        }

        builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(ctx => {
                var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
                return t => c.Resolve(t);
            });


        RegisterDependencies(builder);

        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().As<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        builder.Populate(services);



        var container = builder.Build();
        var serviceProvider = new AutofacServiceProvider(container);

        var mediator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
        return mediator;
    }

    private void RegisterDependencies(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Register modules
    }

}
```

I don't want to work with the `WebApplicationFactory` because the endpoints return a view build on the dto and because the start up takes too long so I thought about writing an integration test only for the mediator request itself which returns the dto but I get this error although I thought I registered the `ISession` with

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpContextAccessor>().As<IHttpContextAccessor>();
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

> Cannot resolve parameter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession session'

The same problem for the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`